# Is there any control like contentplaceholder which is in asp.net for plain html

Tags: asp.net, html, xhtml, dhtml

I have HTML pages like example1.html, example2.html, example3.html, and example4.html. All pages have the same header, footer, and sidebar.

How can I make one master template which replicates any one of those so that I will avoid repeating header and footer code in each of the HTML pages?

My server side will be asmx web services coded in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use MasterPages, in either ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC.  In the Master Page system your common markup goes into a single page (your MasterPage), then ContentPages hold the unique content which fills in the blanks.

Comment: If i use contentplaceholder control my html pages has to be saved as example1.aspx ,example2.aspx but i want my html pages to be saved with .html extension and write server side code

Answer (score 1):

Dont think there is a pure html counterpart for masterpages. you can have a main html page with the common header footer parts hosting other content htmls in an iframe.

Comment: using iframes is best option or creating master template in dreamweaver would be best option .